# arrangement of values that were not selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Ruby on rails

how to make me send an arrangement with the values ​​of radio buttons and checbox that were not selected

For example

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selected_privilege[0]" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="selected_privilege[1]" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="selected_privilege[1]" value="3">
```

for example if you selected the checkbox and the firts radio

```
"selected_privilege"=>{"0" =>"1","1"=>"2"}
```

I also want to send me an arrangement like this

```
"no_selected_privilege"=>{"1" =>"3"}
```

Comment: Why do you want it like that? May be your controller code is easier to modify rather than customizing the params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use hidden fields to send radio/checkbox inputs that are not selected.

for example

```
<input type="radio" name="selected_privilege[1]" value="3">
<input type="hidden" id="no_selected_privilege_three" name="no_selected_privilege[1]" value="3" />
```

with that set up, you can use javascript to empty or add the value of no_selected_privilege[1] if selected_privilege[1] is selected/deselected.

If the hidden fields have a value they will be sent to the server, if they have no value they will not be sent to the server.